# what will be best Approach for Redux-thunk Async Request to handle onSuccess and onError?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

what should be the best approach to manage Redux-Thunk async requests.
like I'm posting some data on server and the connected component will check the errors by

Approach 1: I just return new Promise in my action creators to check resolve or reject by using then

```
const update = (todoId, isDone) => (dispatch) =>
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
dispatch({
  type: 'SET_SAVING',
  saving: true
});
// Function is expected to return a promise
callUpdateApi(todoId, isDone).then(updatedTodo => {
  dispatch({
    type: 'SET_SAVING',
    saving: false
  });

  resolve(updatedTodo);
}).catch(error => {
  // TBD: Handle errors for Redux

  reject(error);
})
});
```

Approach 2: using dispatch to manage error in render method by if-else conditions

```
const update = (todoId, isDone) => (dispatch) => {
dispatch({
    type: 'SET_SAVING',
    saving: true
  });
  // Function is expected to return a promise
  callUpdateApi(todoId, isDone).then(updatedTodo => {
    dispatch({
      type: 'SET_SAVING',
      saving: false
    });
  });
  // TBD: Handle errors
}
```

please help me find the best solution for this
should I go with "return Promise" from Action creators or just using the dispatch actions to store for error and success handling always.
because onsuccess I need to do some stuff in my component and on error also

Answer (score 0):

```
const update = (todoId, isDone) => (dispatch) =>
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
dispatch({
  type: 'SET_SAVING',
  saving: true
});
// Function is expected to return a promise
callUpdateApi(todoId, isDone).then(updatedTodo => {
  dispatch({
    type: 'SET_SAVING',
    saving: false
  });

  resolve(updatedTodo);
}).catch(error => {
  // TBD: Handle errors for Redux

  reject(error);
})
});
```

If your `callUpdateApi` returns a promise you don't have to wrap your whole action in a promise, just can just return `callUpdateApi`. As for error handling, the common way is to set a flag somewhere in your redux state along with the `saving` flag for example to know when an error occured. Your components will then receive those flags and do something with them

```
const update = (todoId, isDone) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({
    type: 'SET_SAVING',
    saving: true
  });

  return callUpdateToApi(todoId, isDone).then(updatedTodo => {
    dispatch({
      type: 'SET_SAVING',
      saving: false,

      // Do something with your API response
      // e.g. update your redux store via a reducer
      updatedTodo
    });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    // Handle error, for example set a error flag
    // in your redux state so your components know an error occured
     dispatch({
      type: 'SET_SAVING',
      saving: false,
      error: true
    });
  });
}
```

Connect your component so that they can access `error` and `saving` flags and for example display an error when your call failed:

```
export default connect(
  state => ({
    error: state.module.error,
    saving: state.module.saving
  })
)(Component);
```

```
// Inside your JSX
{this.props.error && <p>An error occured</p>}
```

Comment: actually, I'm working on a very large project and setting up reducer for error handling increases complexity of my code, because this is just an example I've picked up.
will you please tell me the drawbacks of wrapping the whole action in a promise ?
because it makes my work easier, but I need to follow industry standards, because in future stable implementation will work better. so please suggest the better way ?

Answer (score 0):

the best practice we use is each thunk action dispatched 3 actions:

1. action started
2. action succeeded
3. action failed

`callUpdateApi` is a promise then just return it in your thunk like this:

```
const update = (params) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(started())
  return callUpdateApi(params)
    .then(result => dispatch(succeeded(result)))
    .catch(error => dispatch(failed(error)))
}
```

and inside the reducer you can toggle the `saving` flag for started set it to `true` and for succeeded or failed set it to `false`
that's it.